# Finding a positive fixed point.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A predator-prey model is given by
$f(x,y)=\frac{d}{dt}x = x(r - r\frac{x}{K} - ay) ,r,K,a>0$
$g(x,y)=\frac{d}{dt}y = y(- b + cx) ,b,c>0$
(a) Determine all the fixed points of the system
(b)Determine a condition on K for which a positive fixed point (both the Prey and Predator survive) exists. Find the Jacobian matrix of the sytem.
$\textbf{Ans}$
so I find the zeros of each .
for $\frac{d}{dt}x$ we have $$x(r - r\frac{x}{K} - ay)=0 \implies x=0 \text{ or } (r - r\frac{x}{K} - ay)=0$$ for which$y=\frac{rK-rx}{Ka}.$
Then we do same for $$\frac{d}{dt}y, y(- b + cx)=0,b,c>0 \implies y=0 \text{ or } (- b + cx)=0 \text{ for which }x=\frac{b}{c}$$
for $x=0, g(x,y)=0 \iff y=0$ also for $y=0, f(x,y)=0 \text{ for } x=K$
So we have two fixed points (0,0) and (K,0) but now for part (b) I read that a fixed point is positive if it is non negative and has positive components while in my case y is always zero.Have I missed any fixed point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the point When $$x=b/c, $$ and $$y=\frac{rK-rx}{Ka}, $$ now whats the condition over $K$?

Comment: I tried them in the other equations but didn't get 0 so i thought they weren't fixed points

Comment: They are solutions of $dx/dt=0=dy/dt, $$ aren't they?

Comment: yes,ok I think I confused fixed points with equilibrium points

Comment: so I will have 4 fixed points two each for each function.So for f(x,y) we have x=0 and $y=\frac{rK-rx}{Ka}$ and then for g(x,y) we have y=0 and $x=\frac{b}{c}$ so for K>x we have a positive fixed point

Comment: No, you have a system, so the points must be solutions for both $f$ and $g$, simultaneously. Also the condition for positivity is $K>b/c$ not $K>x$ since $x$ is a variable

Comment: ok,for $y=\frac{rK-rx}{Ka}$ into g(x,y) x is either $\frac{b}{c}$ or K and then the fixed points are $(K,\frac{rK-rx}{Ka})$ and $(\frac{b}{c},\frac{rK-rx}{Ka})$?